# Test framework architecture using Selenium WebDriver and TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, testng

guys. I trying to solve a problem with parallel running using RC Webdriver and TestNG, but unfortunately, I can't find solution last few hours. Maby you will see the code, and show me what, I actually doing wrong.
**Goal:**
Create architecture using RC WebDriver and TestNG, with an ability to run tests on a remote machine.

Main settings class is **Sut**:

```
private RemoteWebDriver driver = null;

@BeforeClass
public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
    DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
    dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, fp);
    dc.setBrowserName(DesiredCapabilities.firefox().getBrowserName());
    try {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), dc);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return driver;
}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

In this class we have two methods: getWebDriver() - for setup our remote webdriver, and tearDown() - for close web-page, when a test will be complete.

Class **BaseStep**:

```
private static ThreadLocal<Sut> sut = new ThreadLocal<Sut>();

public static Sut getSut() {
    Sut currentSut = sut.get();
    if (currentSut == null) {
        currentSut = new Sut();
    }
    return currentSut;
}
```

It's an additional layer, which create 'new state for each new thread'.

Few page objects:

```
 public class FacebookPage {
        public void testLink() {
            getSut().getWebDriver().get("http://facebook.com");
        }
    }

public class GooglePage {
        public void testLink() {
            getSut().getWebDriver().get("http://google.com");
        }
    }
```

And scenarious classes:

```
public class VerifyGooglePage {
    GooglePage googlePage = new GooglePage();

    @Test
    public void verifyGoogleMainPage() {
        googlePage.testLink();
    }
}

public class VerifyFacebookPage {
    Facebook facebookPage = new Facebook();

    @Test
    public void verifyFacebookeMainPage() {
        facebookPage.testLink();
    }
}
```

And my and **testNG.xml** file for running

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="1" name="Suite" parallel="tests">
    <test name="FirstTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="scenarious.VerifyGooglePage"/>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
    <test name="SecondTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="scenarious.VerifyFacebookPage"/>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

The problems is: When test complete, **browser is not closed**. 
[the Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f2q7.png)

I watched a lot of tutorials and articles in internet about it, but in no-one I cant found solution for my case. Could you please help me to find what I doing wrong.